# Auto number with specific start value in CUBA Framework

Tags: cuba-platform

How can I start the auto number from any specific value say, 1000 in CUBA platform?

Answer (score 1):

In the running application, go to Administration > JMX Console, find the `app-core.cuba:type=UniqueNumbers` MBean and invoke its `setCurrentNumber()` method, passing your sequence name (say `abc`) and desired starting number (`1000`).

If you need to do this programmatically, obtain a reference to the `UniqueNumbersAPI` bean available on middleware and invoke its `setCurrentNumber()` method.